# Add categorical variable in crr of package cmprsk

Tags: r, error-message, competing-risks

My magelastbirth_pctl is a categorical variable with 5 levels. I want to calculate the hazard ratio of the 4 last categories compared to the first categories using Fine and Gray competing risk model.

This is easy to do with normal cox model using the following code

```
elcs.cox_CoD = coxph(Surv(fuptime, status_CoD==17) ~ factor(magelastbirth_pctl) +
                                                     factor(magefirstbirth_pctl) +
                                                     totchildren +
                                                     prochildrendeceased_bef18 + byr_cat +
                                                     factor(npses_husb_high_qtl),
                     data = elcs6)
```

However, I don't know how to do it using crr command. It works if I treat the magelastbirth_pctl as a continuous variable per the following code

```
elcs.cmprsk = crr(ftime=elcs6$fuptime, fstatus=elcs6$status_CoD, failcode=1, cencode=0,
              cov1=elcs.cov)
```

I tried to use the FGR command of the riskRegressions package

```
test = FGR(Hist(fuptime,status_CoD)~factor(magelastbirth_pctl)+factor(magefirstbirth_pctl) + 
                                    totchildren + prochildrendeceased_bef18 + byr_cat,
           data=elcs6)
```

but it kept giving me the error "Argument cause missing. Analyse cause: 1"

Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong? There are surprisingly limited examples in cmprsk and none of them mentioned categorical data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a `model.matrix`:

```
cov1 <- model.matrix(~ factor(magelastbirth_pctl) + factor(magefirstbirth_pctl) +
                       totchildren + prochildrendeceased_bef18 + byr_cat +
                       factor(npses_husb_high_qtl),
                     data = elcs6)[, -1]
crr(ftime=elcs6$fuptime, fstatus=elcs6$status_CoD, failcode=1, cencode=0, cov1=cov1)
```

from `?cmprsk::crr`

> the `model.matrix` function can be used to generate suitable matrices of covariates from factors, eg `model.matrix(~factor1+factor2)[,-1]` will generate the variables for the factor coding of the factors `factor1` and `factor2`. The final `[,-1]` removes the constant term from the output of `model.matrix`

For a formula interface, see `survival::finegray`

```
library('cmprsk')
fg <- finegray(Surv(futime, event) ~ age + sex + abo, na.omit(transplant),
               etype = 'death')
coef(
  coxph(Surv(fgstart, fgstop, fgstatus) ~ age + sex + abo, fg, weights = fgwt)
)
#        age        sexf        aboB       aboAB        aboO 
# 0.01890731 -0.42597601  0.39092581  0.13277852  0.38908033
```

Or `cmprsk2` which is still under development but includes some useful functions for `cmprsk` including a formula interface, `crr2`

```
# devtools::install_github('raredd/cmprsk2')
library('cmprsk2')
c2 <- crr2(Surv(futime, event(censored) == death) ~ age + sex + abo,
           na.omit(transplant))
coef(c2$`CRR: death`)
#        age        sexf        aboB       aboAB        aboO 
# 0.01890467 -0.42585553  0.39078253  0.13283606  0.38898005
```

If you look at the call for the model, it will tell you what needed to be ran in order to get this fit (including how to construct the model matrix)

```
c2$`CRR: death`$call

# crr(na.omit(transplant)[, "futime"], na.omit(transplant)[, "event"], 
#     cov1 = model.matrix(~age + sex + abo, na.omit(transplant))[, 
#         -1L, drop = FALSE], cencode = "censored", failcode = "death", 
#     variance = TRUE)

eval(c2$`CRR: death`$call)

# convergence:  TRUE 
# coefficients:
#     age    sexf    aboB   aboAB    aboO 
#  0.0189 -0.4259  0.3908  0.1328  0.3890 
# standard errors:
# [1] 0.01116 0.25350 0.38170 0.62300 0.28140
# two-sided p-values:
#   age  sexf  aboB aboAB  aboO 
# 0.090 0.093 0.310 0.830 0.170
```

Comment: cmprsk2 seems great! However, why are the coefficients slightly different between the 2 function?

Comment: @DanChaltiel hmm, good point. I'm not sure, but it seems to do with how `finegray` handles discrete time (or times with ties). For example, if you add a tiny amount of noise to the time variable, you get the same coefficients: run `transplant$futime <- transplant$futime + runif(nrow(transplant), 0, 0.1)` first then fit the models. There is a line in `finegray` which is `newtime <- matrix(findInterval(Y[, 1:2], utime), ncol = 2)` where `utime` are unique times, so that may be the culprit

Answer (score 1):

The abovementioned answer is great, just to mention one tiny detail in the matrix;

```
cov1 <- model.matrix(~factor(magelastbirth_pctl) + factor(magefirstbirth_pctl) +
                       totchildren + prochildrendeceased_bef18 + byr_cat +
                       factor(npses_husb_high_qtl),
                     data = elcs6)[, -1]
```

The `~` sign is essential to prevent errors like `'+' is not meaningful for factors`